# Can you recommend a Sql Server 2008 book for developers that only addresses the new features?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a book that only addresses the *new* development features of Sql Server 2008.   I had read "A First Look at Sql Server 2005 for Developers" years ago but cannot find an equivalent book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked this one up recently and it has a good focus on 2008 specific items:

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Server-2008-PRO-Developer/dp/0735625999/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1242660997&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625999)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice list here 
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/whats-new.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could also just check out MS books online and see the new features.   You can use any of the above to dive deeper into any topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Apress has good books: [http://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-Server-2008-Robert-Walters/dp/1590599691/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1242658972&sr=1-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599691)

This one seems to be good too: [http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-Server%C2%AE-2008-Step-Microsoft/dp/0735626049/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1242658972&sr=1-7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626049)

Answer (score 0):

The new development features in SQL 2008 don't really merit a whole book by themselves, with one exception - geospatial data.  If you're using geospatial, then check into specific books on that, but otherwise the improvements aren't really book-worthy.

Andy Warren wrote up a short review of one 2008 developer-focused book, but that's the only review I've seen from a SQL expert focusing on a 2008 developer book.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/andy_warren/archive/2009/03/10/book-review-murach-s-sql-server-2008-for-developers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I went with two books which I can now recommend to others:

1) Microsoft Sql Server New Features by Michael Otey

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-Server-2008-Features-Microsoft/dp/0071546405/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1245288147&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071546405)

2) Programming Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (PRO-Developer)

Covers new features of both 2005 and 2008 and in greater detail.

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Server-2008-PRO-Developer/dp/0735625999/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1245288368&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625999)